# Why is there a difference in values when I am reading from oracle DB and storing the retrieved number in a string.

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Why is there a difference in values when I am reading a column value(stored as float data type in DB) from oracle DB and storing the retrieved number in a string. For eg. The column stores .0286949901125447 but when this is read from the DB using Java JDBCTemplate it outputs .028694990112544703. I am using Oracle 10.2. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: That is why many a times you might want to use the `BigDecimal` type in Java.

Comment: Which db client are you using?

Comment: @Lion converting from BigDecimal in Java and float in the DB would probably be quite lossy.

Comment: @Thilo : It's for this reason, I never use `float` or `double` type in DB too. I always use an appropriate type in DB that can precisely map `BigDecimal` in Java.

Comment: @Lion: that is very sound advice. However, it seems that the DB is float now. Unless that can be changed (which OP should investigate), we probably have to go with it.

Comment: I am using PL/SQL Developer. Its not possible to change the data type at this point of time.

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to give you an exact answer because you have not shared any code with us. However I believe that the value into DB and into string is the same. Simply the tool you are using to view data in DB formats the values and probably removes the tail, so you just do not see the last 2 characters `02`.

Comment: I am using PL/SQL Developer. Can you tell what could be the problem with this?

Comment: @AbhishekSahu, try to run a query similar to [this one](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eb470/7) and see

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide: http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Use BigDecimal in java to avoid rounding errors.

Comment: Not sure that is a good option, seeing that the data in the DB is floating point.

Comment: I can't change the data type now. Any other suggestions?